# How do I make ruby 1.9.3 write newlines to a text file?

Tags: ruby, windows, text-files, newline

I'm using Windows 7. With Ruby 1.8.7, writing to a text file with `puts` added a newline so that these irb commands:

```
my_file = File.new("C:\\new_file.txt", "w+")
my_file.puts("first line")
my_file.puts("\n\n")
my_file.puts("")
my_file.puts("fifth line")
my_file.close
```

results in a text file that reads:

> first line
>
> ...three blank lines here (the editor seems to be stripping newlines
>   too)
>
> fifth line

In Ruby 1.9.3, the newlines are stripped, even when I try to force one by adding a `\n`, resulting in a text file that reads:

> first linefifth line

Does anyone know what changed and what I need to do to restore newlines to my file?

Comment: In Notepad, are the newlines apparent?

Comment: I get your Ruby 1.8.7 result. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!  I'm looking at the text file in notepad and there are no newlines.  Should I be using something else?

Comment: What is the result of `my_file.puts("line1","line2","line3")` ? And what does `my_file.puts($/.inspect)` and `my_file.puts($\.inspect)` show you?

Comment: I just tried your code in 1.9.3-p194, it works just fine. Try writing out a limited number of characters and check the file size: a `puts "first line\nlast line"` should show a file size of 20 bytes (unless a UTF-8 file is created, in which case it will be larger - experiment writing one character and see what you get, and then calculate using that info)

Comment: You might also try writing in binary mode and see what you get (replace `w+` with `wb+`)

Answer (score 7):

In Windows the newline is a carriage return and a newline character, so you must use this:

```
myfile.puts("\r\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but adding the carriage return didn't add new lines either.

Comment: Thanks @AkosKovacs I have exactly same issue and this works like a charm!